# Can framerate be randomized?

Tags: edit-mode

Is it possible to randomize the framerate within one video?

For example, if I have a video shot at 25 fps, is there a way to make this video randomly play between 10 and 40 fps at different times during the video?  The goal would be to produce a 'glitchy' look when the video is viewed.

I only need to know if this is possible; I don't need to know many details.  Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: Why would you want to randomize the framerate and what is the effect you are trying to achieve ... posting a video of a similar effect may help others understand the question better. I say this because seldom would anyone do this. If this is an intended effect ... well I can only think of one good way of doing it ...

Comment: This will require a **huge** amount of unnecessary computation, so I'm not writing it as an answer, but you could render your "glitchy" scene at highest possible fps, remove images randomly, rename them to be sequential and then convert to video.

Answer (score 2):

Your final video will have a constant frame rate, but you can cut and mix pieces of video into your final output that play at altered speeds from their original source.

You most likely want to use the *Effect Strip->Speed Control*. There is also a strobe property for a video strip. Don't be afraid to keyframe properties to get varying effects during the length of your video.